# How can I determine the height and width of a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, height, layout-manager

I have been making a program where I have created a `JFrame` with a `BorderLayout` distribution. On the center I have a class extended from a `JPanel` called `AreaDibujo` where I use a `BufferedImage`. In order to use this buffered image properly, I need to pass two `int` parameters on its constructor, the height and width it will cover.

How can I make it cover all the panel? AKA how do I determinate my panel size (the program runs on fullscreen)?

Here is an image of how does the program look so far:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGCLa.png]

Comment: *How can I make it cover all the JPanel?* - an easy way is to use a JLabel with the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). The image will automatically be resized to fill the space available.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I determine the height and width of a `JPanel`?
> .. I have a class extended from a `JPanel` called `AreaDibujo`

Since it seems the code is using custom painting, the height and width of the panel can be determined when the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method is called, using `this.getWidth()` and `this.getHeight()`..